# How to store user profile information and access it globally in react components

Tags: reactjs, passport.js

I am using a passport for authenticating the user. After successful authentication, I would like to show the username and id in one of the react components for now. There could be more places where I need to access user information in the future.

How should I accessing user profile information in independent react components?

I tried storing the user information in a cookie. Accessing the cookie in every component seems to be messy.

```
app.post('/login/callback', auth.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true }), function (req, res) {
// stores the cookie information
    res.cookie('cookie1', req.user.id, { secure: true, signed: true, expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600) });
    res.redirect('/');
   }
);
```

I would like to access the user principal globally across all the react components.

Answer (score 12):

There are multiple options for Global State management.

1. [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage): Use the Browser local storage to save details
2. [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage): This is similar to Local Storage with just one difference: that is while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.
3. [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html): Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components
4. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/): Use State management library to manage the state in one place.

Comment: Which of these options is used the most / is the most elegant?

Comment: It depends on the way you want to use it. Local storage provides a persistent solution and could be useful to store cookies(Authentication and Authorization). The same applies to the session storage inside a session which provides more security. Context and redux are the volatile solutions. Could be useful to store user preferences and temp data that will be persisted somewhere else.